# Rails: How to handle multiple subscriptions for one user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm able to assign multiple subscriptions to a user, but the problem is that everytime I assign a new subscription to a user, I'm overriding the `subscription_id`.

I can still show the user all his subscriptions through `Stripe::Subscription.list(current_user.stripe_id)`, but it's not possible to show a specific subscription, just the last one that was created.

The code I'm currently using:

```
customer = if current_user.stripe_id?
             Stripe::Customer.retrieve(current_user.stripe_id)
           else
             Stripe::Customer.create(
               email: current_user.email,
               source: params[:stripeToken]
             )
           end

begin
  product = Stripe::Product.retrieve(@order.project)
rescue Stripe::InvalidRequestError => e
  if e.response.http_status == 404
  product = Stripe::Product.create(
    id: @order.project, # Unqiue Identifier -> In Ordnung etc
    name: @order.project, # Produkt name -> In Ordnung
    statement_descriptor: 'Mediadesign Web',
    metadata: {"Module" => @order.moduls},
    type: 'service'
  )
  end
 end

begin
  plan = Stripe::Plan.retrieve(product.id)
rescue Stripe::InvalidRequestError => e
  if e.response.http_status == 404
    plan  = Stripe::Plan.create(
      id: product.id,
      nickname: @order.nickname,
      product: product.id,
      amount: @order.price * 100,
      currency: 'eur',
      interval: 'month'
    )
  end
end

subscription = customer.subscriptions.create(
  plan: plan.id
)

current_user.update(
 stripe_id: customer.id,
 subscription_id: subscription.id
 )

  redirect_to webdesigns_order_subscriptions_path
```

Answer (score 0):

See doc: https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions

Basically the concept is:

Subscriptions allow you to charge a customer on a recurring basis. A subscription ties a customer to a particular plan you've created.

Plans define the base price, currency, and billing cycle for subscriptions

Subscription items allow you to create customer subscriptions with more than one plan, making it easy to represent complex billing relationships.

In short, customer will be subscribed through plan.

You can retrieve the plan by passing the plan_id...
See doc: https://stripe.com/docs/api/plans/retrieve

If you want to fetch particular subscription...
See doc: https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/retrieve

For particular Subscription_item...
See doc: https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscription_items/object

For plan
https://stripe.com/docs/api/plans

Hope it helps :)